# "Select Media" chooser in Drupal site no longer works

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've inherited the content upkeep on a local non-profit's website. The site is running Drupal 7.71. There's an employee/staff section on the site, and the admin interface has the ability to add new employees, and to modify the content of current employees. My issue is with the "Select Media" button in the interface that allows us to add an employee photo. When it was working properly, clicking on that button launched a modal overlay that allowed me to upload a new image, or choose a pre-existing one. Once I did that the modal would vanish, and I'd be back to the original employee admin form, with the selected image added.

Now for some reason when I click on the "Select Media" button the modal appears for a split second, but then it changes to a full HTML page, as if the browser's location.href has changed to the URL of the modal. I can pick/upload an image, but then have to navigate back to the original employee entry page, and when I do it does not show that any image has been selected.

As far as I know I have made no changes to the site that could be causing this change in behavior. I specifically have not done any updates to the Drupal install or any of the modules (I don't want to attempt any sort of code updates until we have a robust backup/rollback system in place). I don't see any JavaScript errors in the console when attempting to use this functionality, and the error occurs in multiple different browsers, so I don't think it's browser related.

Anyone have any idea what's going on, and how to fix it?

Comment: Check the issue queue for which ever media browser module is being used on the site.

Comment: Caution, maybe you don't see any error because the dev console is cleared as soon as the browser's location change. You can try to add a listener for the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event and invoke the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) within the handler, once the code breaks at that point, check the call stack in order to find the root cause of the page load.

Comment: Thanks @EricLavault ! I have my dev console set to persist logs to nothing's getting wiped by the URL change. But that's a great idea about adding a listener at beforeunload , I'll try that. Thanks!